# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied' error while Automating a WPF app using FlaUI+SpecFlow

Tags: c#, wpf, process, specflow, flaui

I have landed up in a problem that doesn't occur very frequently. I am trying to automate the `UI testing` using `FlaUI and SpecFlow`. I am trying to launch the app `exe`.`The app runs for sometime and then throws the error.`  I am getting the error below.

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'

Code:

```
public void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.Info("Synergy TestHub starting up in memory");

                _testHub = new SynergyTestHub(locator =>
                {
                    locator.RegisterFeatureService(Substitute.For<ISynergyLogger>());
                    locator.RegisterFeatureService(Substitute.For<ISynergyClientConfigService>());
                }, Config.SynergyEnvironment);


                // Run the Synergy Test Hub In Memory
                AsyncBlockingDeadlockAvoidanceHack.SafeWait(
                    async () => await _testHub.RunUiApplicationAsync(
                        _pathBuilder.ShipTrackerExePath,
                        600,
                        false));

                _controlAction.WaitFor(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 50)); // Average time for ref data to load

                var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(Config.ShipTrackerFileName)[0];
                process.WaitForInputIdle();
                Application = Application.Attach(process.Id);
                ShipTrackerWindow = GetMainWindow();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Error Starting up Synergy TestHub in Memory. {exception.Message}");
                _logger.Warning("Killing processes that could be hanging around .. please try to run the test again");
                _processTerminator.KillProcess(new List<string>
                {
                    Config.ShipTrackerFileName, Config.SynergyHubAppName

                });

                throw;
            }
        }
```

The `StackTrace` is

Stack Trace:

```
ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
Process.WaitForInputIdle(Int32 milliseconds)
Process.WaitForInputIdle()
ApplicationDriver.Start() line 79
Hooks.BeforeScenario() line 133
lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) line 69
TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType) line 351
TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType) line 340
TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent) line 321
TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioStart() line 198
TestRunner.OnScenarioStart() line 54
RefreshTheViewsFeature.ScenarioStart()
RefreshTheViewsFeature.AutomationOfRefreshInManualPublishMode() line 34
```

The line `process.WaitForInputIdle();` throws the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have permission to read all the process in your device, try to run as administrator mode

Comment: I was able to run other test cases. I am just reading the current app exe process and it was all working perfect a little while ago. This is a new bug that showed up

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by having an active RDP session. In the github issues section, I saw that [someone had the exact same issue](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI/issues/408#issuecomment-1230221611) when he was trying to click on an item. He was able to get around this problem by having an active local VNC session going.

I have also seen mentions of using .Invoke on a button instead of using the .Click/LeftMouseClick etc., but I have not been able to fully convert my program to only use InvokePatterns for controlling the UI.